# Why no runtime error with this generics code?

Tags: java, generics

I have this code

```
    ArrayList<Integer>arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add(1);
    arr.add(2);

    List l = arr;
    l.add("12");// should't this throw an runtime exception? Point1 
    l.add("123");
    System.out.println(l.size());
    ArrayList<String>arr1 =(ArrayList<String>) l;// should't this throw an runtime execptions? Point2 

    arr1.add("12"); //Point 3
    System.out.println(arr1.size());
```

I was experimenting with generics code, and I am surprised to see some of the results. I have this specific questions.

I have a arraylist of integer. I assign it to a list l, which does not have any generic type. I then add a string to that list. Shouldn't this throw a runtime exception? l list is still a arraylist of integer?

I then cast l to arraylist of string? Shouldn't this also throw a runtime exception? Ain't I effectively casting arraylist of integer to ararylist of string?

And in this case point 3, I am adding a string to arr1, even though it is supposed to be arraylist of string?

I feel like all of the three questioned are related? can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics are enforced at compile time so that the compiler can do type checking.  However, through *[type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)*, the information about the type is actually not used at runtime.  Rather, collections all just contain `Object`.  I believe this was originally done to retain bytecode compatibility with previous java versions which didn't have generics support.

You should, however, get some warnings about using raw types.

Comment: so no runtime exception is expected to occur?

Comment: Correct -- it is legal (however generally discouraged) to store heterogeneous types in the same collection.  In order to usefully process the list, you'd need to make use of `instanceof` or otherwise encode the type of a particular element.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are erased at runtime, therefore it is possible but highly frowned upon to get any types in a `List` through casting. This is possible because the compiled code sees it as just a `List`, no generics. This can cause many problems if you pass the list to any methods, and you **will** get a runtime error. Generally, you should get an 'unchecked' warning with things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1 : A raw List can contain any Object, if you want to enforce typechecking (at compile time) for the content of the List, you need to specify its content type. When you assign `arr` to `l`, you lose the ability to enforce typechecking, no Exception is thus thrown and it's what is expected.

Point 2 : casting a List to an ArrayList "might be possible" (that's why there is no compilation error) as ArrayList implements List. However, as stated in point 1, you lost the ability to enforce typechecking at compile time (assigning directly `arr` to `arr1` won't generate a compile error) that's why you have no ClassCastException. Note that you could even assign a `new LinkedList()`to `l` then assign `l` to `arr1`and it would have compiled (but it would have raised a class cast exception at runtime as in this case the cast is detected as being impossible at runtime)

Point 3 : it is an ArrayList of Strings, you add a String, it's typesafe.

Comment: I understand no compile time exception being through. I was expecting classcast exception at point 2. could you explain how it does not throw a class cast?

Comment: Type of ``l`` is ``List`` (not ``ArrayList<Integer>`` anymore), can an object of type ``List`` be an ``ArrayList<String>`` ? Yes, it is *possible* (but can't be verified at compile time so there is no error message during compilation). At compile time, however, verification is done that you insert ``String`` instances into ``arr1`` (that's why you can add ``"12"``, but can't add ``12``), at runtime you're casting an ``ArrayList`` to an ``ArrayList`` (no generics at runtime), and therefore there is no class cast exception.